# SQL DB2 sql error INCORRECT SYNTAX

Tags: sql-server, db2, syntax-error, linked-server

What am I missing in this code below that will cause the error:

> Msg 170, level 15, line 113 line 113:
>   Incorrect syntax near
>   'actual_completion_date'.

```
update #Loss_mit_step
set
 [STEP924_COMPL_DATE] = Case when step_code ='924' then ls_actual_completion_date else ' ' end,
 [STEP926_COMPL_DATE] = Case when step_code ='926' then ls_actual_completion_date else ' ' end,
 [STEP927_COMPL_DATE] = Case when step_code ='927' then ls_actual_completion_date else ' ' end,
 [STEP928_COMPL_DATE] = Case when step_code ='928' then ls_actual_completion_date else ' ' end,
 [APPROVAL_DATE] = Case when step_code ='Q28' then ls_actual_completion_date else ' ' end
```

Comment: Please format your code. Select it in the editor and press Control-K.

Comment: @marc: that was my edit. I assumed this was like his previous questions, where he's using a DB2 linked server. Maybe this one is pure T-SQL?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have an extra comma in the statement, at the very end.

---

I suggest you comment out each of the "case" lines, one by one, until you find out what the problem is, or until you only have one line left.

Answer (score 2):

What you posted is syntactically correct, so you cannot get a syntax error. It actually parses fine. Your error message mentions `actual_completion_date` but you have no such token in your post. So obviously you posted an error from a different T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the error: a space in front of actual_completion_date on the first line.

Comment: You edited to remove the trailing comma that John Saunders noted. Anyway, I see no space above...

Comment: next time, post the entire query, the tiny fragment you posted was not what you fixed, there is no space in it.